# string expansion algo in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, algorithm

I'm trying to write code which does following using python3.
input 3[as] = asasas
input 3[b2[ac]] = bacacbacacbacac

I'm not getting something right with substrings. Any help appreciated.

Here is my code -

```
def parse_string(pattern) :
    if len(pattern) == 0 :
        return
    
    open_bracket = []
    close_Bracket = []
    
    for i in range(len(pattern)) :
        if (pattern[i] == '[') :
            open_bracket.append(i)
        if (pattern[i] == ']') :
            close_Bracket.append(i)
            
    print("open brackets - ", open_bracket)
    print("Closed bracket ", close_Bracket)
    
    rev = open_bracket[::-1]
    outputstr = {}
    index = 0
    for i in range(len(rev)) :
        token = pattern[rev[i]+1:index+close_Bracket[i]]
        multiplier = pattern[rev[i]-1:rev[i]]
        #build new string
        new_str = int(multiplier) * (token)
        pattern = pattern.replace(pattern[rev[i]-1:index+close_Bracket[i]+1], new_str)
        index = index + len(new_str) - 3 - len(token) # 4 sums up to replacing open and close bracket and number -1
        outputstr[pattern[rev[i]-1:close_Bracket[i]+1]] = new_str
```

which produces output - bacacac]bacacac] for input 2[b3[ac]]. Is there a better way to get the output?
TIA

**Edit** The edited code now works and produces output as expected. I think Daniel's answer below is clean and readable.

Comment: The code will fail at the line: `token .... ` list index out of range.  Are you sure it's the complete code?

Comment: It is complete code. I fixed calculating index and now it works. If I look at the code, it is too much of string manipulation and 2 pass.  I was interested in looking at a different, concise and faster way of getting to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Congrats on fixing the original post and make it works. It's better to add `Edit` to make it clear next time...  Do you have reviewed mine and find any usefulness?

Comment: I liked yours, clean and concise. Thanks

Comment: Glad that I can help. Would you vote for the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two versions presented here as alternative of *"better"* approach, first using **stack** (more intuitive), second using re module (that I came across).  Since the definition of "better" is not clear, these just for cross reference/to be considered and commented.

But the first version is more readable and faster than PO.

```
def parseString(s: str):
    curnum = 0
    curstring = ''
    stack = []
     for char in s:
         if char == '[':
             stack.append(curstring)
             stack.append(curnum)
             curstring = ''
             curnum = 0
         elif char == ']':
             prenum = stack.pop()
             prestring = stack.pop()
             curstring = prestring + prenum * curstring
         elif char.isdigit():
              curnum = curnum * 10 + int(char)
         else:
             curstring += char
        return curstring
```

```
  import re
  def parseString(s: str) -> str:
      while '[' in s:
              s = re.sub(r'(\d+)\[([a-z]*)\]', lambda m: int(m.group(1)) * m.group(2), s)
     return s
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, found answer. I just fixed the index part to

index = index + len(new_str) - 3 - len(token)